# Does the myTouch 4g Slide require a data plan?

Tags: data-plan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smartphone without the expensive data plan](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12250/smartphone-without-the-expensive-data-plan)

I was wondering because I was going to get it but I can not afford the data plan and needed to know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're interested in using it just as a calling / messaging device, you are in no need of any data plan.

Answer (score 1):

Is there is nothing special about the myTouch the answer is: **No Android smartphone requires a data plan, but it's no fun without a data plan.**

The phone works perfectly fine without a data plan ( of course, syncs won't happen ). The major disadvantage is that you have carefully check that you don't accidentally transfer any data while connected to your mobile carrier, because this results usually in high fees. But Android has a nice setting to disable mobile data permanently. This should keep you safe.

Comment: Some carriers won't sell you a smartphone (or allow them on their network) without some form of data plan, particularly in the US.